# Cómo puedo especificar permisos a un bucket S3 para que solo se acceda por mi app de react?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, aws, amazon-s3

Mi problema es el siguiente: quiero mostrar imágenes de un bucket S3 privado, pero quiero que se vean únicamente en mi página, es decir, que si yo obtengo la URL de la imagen y la coloquen en el navegador tal cual está aparezca como que no se tienen los permisos, esto se puede hacer desde aws? O lo hago desde un backend?

### intentos

Lo que estoy haciendo es que obtengo mi imagen desde mi backend y lo transformo en un arraybyte y se lo envio a mi frontend y ya lo coloco en mi etiqueta img

Comment: y qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Lo que estoy haciendo es que obtengo mi imagen desde mi backend y lo transformo en un arraybyte y se lo envio a mi frontend y ya lo coloco en mi etiqueta img